# Can I let mean_iou depend on update_op? Both of them are returned by tf.metrics.mean_iou()

Tags: python, python-3.x, tensorflow, metrics

Inspired by API of

```
accuracy, update_op = tf.metrics.accuracy()
```

which said I can only use

```
acc_value = sess.run(update_op)
```

to get the most updated accumulated accuracy value and update the accuracy at the same time.

But I didn't find the a similar feature in API of

```
mean_iou, update_op = tf.metrics.mean_iou()
```

So, can I use

```
with tf.control_dependencies([update_op]):
    get_miou_value_and_update_it = mean_iou

# in a session
sess.run(get_miou_value_and_update_it,feed_dict={...})
```

to perform similar function?

Answer (score 1):

No, you would have to add an identity operation, otherwise you are not creating any actual dependency:

```
mean_iou, update_op = tf.metrics.mean_iou()
with tf.control_dependencies([update_op]):
    get_miou_value_and_update_it = tf.identity(mean_iou)
```